# How to create expandable table in react?

Tags: reactjs, material-table, expandable-table

I have been trying for a while to create a table with expandable rows. And in the expandable row, i wanted to display a table with header and row data. 
I tried different modules like Material-UI Table and material-table. 
I can display a card for e.g., in the expandable row. But not a table with .
Does anyone know how to do this in react js?

thanks in advance

Comment: https://adazzle.github.io/ try it

Comment: check out [react-table](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-table-6)